# Docker multistage build nextjs - why three stage?

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, docker-multi-stage-build

I have been looking into optimising our docker images and have been implementing multi stage builds as part of this.

From my understanding the benefit is that the final image can be a streamlined version that simply has all the needed files copied in from the previous build stages, meaning it doesn't need all the various tools and packages involved during the build process.

However all the examples I've seen for building a nextjs docker image seem to have three stages, one to install the node modules, one to build the app, then the final version, for example this one:

```dockerfile
    # Stage 1: install dependencies
    FROM node:17-alpine AS deps
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY package*.json .
    ARG NODE_ENV
    ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV
    RUN npm install
    
    # Stage 2: build
    FROM node:17-alpine AS builder
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
    COPY src ./src
    COPY public ./public
    COPY package.json next.config.js jsconfig.json ./
    RUN npm run build
    
    # Stage 3: run
    FROM node:17-alpine
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
    COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
    COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
    COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./
    CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

What does this give you that a two stage doesn't? i.e. why wouldn't you just have the install and build in the same stage, it seems to me that the final image would end up exactly the same either way?

Comment: I would think that a project with a lot of deps wouldn't want to redownload those every deploy if deps didn't change.

Comment: I agree that there isn't a huge difference from just having 2 stages. NODE_ENV isn't set in stage 2 if that makes a difference. And if you have a package-lock.json file, that's only used in stage 1.

Comment: Reading through that specific setup, it seems all but identical to what you'd get from a _single_ stage, even.  I can imagine some setups where it makes sense (have a specific build stage that uses `devDependencies`; maybe installing a dependency needs a C toolchain but not running it) but this particular Dockerfile doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: @zero298 Docker's layer cache should take care of that whether it's a single stage or multiple